# Finding out the number of needed macro arguments

Tags: macros, arguments

How can I find out how many arguments (i.e. {} pairs) are used when 'calling' a macro? (my favorite error, that I extend a macro, i.e. it needs one more argument, then I use it to compile a text prepared for a macro having one less argument. I receive a variety of errors, depending of the environment of the macro call in the text.)

In other words: can I find out within the macro, whether it was called
with the right number of {} arguments?

Comment: Look at the documentation that defines the macro? Or even take a look at the macro definition.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{xparse} \NewDocumentCommand\macro{gggg}{\IfValueTF{#4}{<your definition with #1, #2, #3, and #4>}{<what you want to output in case of error>}`. You just have to write the letter `g` the numer of times of the argument (`gggg` in case of four arguments), and also `\IfValueTF{#4}` should have also the last argument. For instance, if you want seven arguments, you can `ggggggg` and `\IfValueTF{#7}`. But it's *not* perfect, and you better do whatever other approach to get to where you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you define "number of macro arguments" the answer may or may not be obtainable from tex and you may need to rely on the package documentation.

If you do

```
\newcommand\fooa[2]{abc}

\show\fooa
```

you see

```
> \fooa=\long macro:
#1#2->abc.
```

So you could take this `#1#2->` as one definition of the command taking two `{}` arguments

but if you do

```
\newcommand\foob[2][]{abc}

\show\foob
```

Then you may document that as being one optional `[]` argument and one `{}` argument but `\show` shows the primitive definition:

```
> \foob=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \foob \\foob {}.
```

`\foob` technically takes no arguments at all.

Similarly after

```
\newcommand\fooc{\fooa}
```

Then `\fooc` operates in almost all contexts just like `\fooa` and acts as if it takes two arguments but

```
\show\fooc
```

shows

```
> \fooc=\long macro:
->\fooa .
```

confirming that it has no arguments at all as a primitive control sequence definition.

Comment: I'm more into `\meaning` :)

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed reply, maybe I asked the wrong way. I would like to find out within the macro, whether the user provided sufficient number of {} terms. If not, it would be better to provide a well defined error, than to receive a message informing about a wide variety of syntax errors.

Comment: @katang you can't: TeX will have picked up the 'required' number of `<balanced text>` arguments or given an error. You might of course find that what TeX thinks are the arguments are not what was intended!

Comment: @katang you can't every really do that as the `{}` are optional if you omit them you just get the next tokens so if you forget a section title `\section Once upon a time` then you can not (easily) give an error that the `{}` argument is missing as the input is identical to `\section{O}nce upon a time` so the section argument is provided, and is `O`.