# How beamer notices an empty line between title and subtitle?

Tags: beamer, optional-arguments, frame-title

Referrring back to my question
[Finding out the number of needed macro arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319628/finding-out-the-number-of-needed-macro-arguments) :
how Beamer can find out whether a {} term is subtitle or not?
I see that an empty line makes the difference; my question is how can I notice that there is and empty line between arguments? And how safe this technique is? (I suffered a lot with frames, sometimes misinterpreting my first character, when the frame content was not preceeded by and empty line.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections] {Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec one}
\subsection{OneOne}
\begin{frame}{Frame Number 1}{Frame 1}
{1}
\end{frame}
\subsection{OneTwo}
\begin{frame}{Frame Number 2}
{Frame 2}

{2}
\end{frame}
\section{Sec two}
\subsection{TwoOne}
\begin{frame}{Frame Number 3}

{Frame 3}
{3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer checks the presence of an opening {

```
\@ifnextchar\bgroup
```

See macro `\beamer@checkframetitle` in file beamerbaseframe.sty